# jquery solution / javascript function assign variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, onclick

i need function which assign selected value or variable to new variable and forward to input field. Anyone can help me? :>

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
    //function 
}
</script>

<input id="price-postfix1" onclick="myFunction()" name="price-postfix" type="radio" value="$option1"/>Option1<br>
<input id="price-postfix2" onclick="myFunction()" name="price-postfix" type="radio" value="$option2"/>Option1<br>
<input id="price-postfix3" onclick="myFunction()" name="price-postfix" type="radio" value="$option3"/>Option1<br>

<input id="price-postfix" name="price-postfix" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="$result"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass current object to function `myFunction` using `this`

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/6uz8p2bb/)

```
<input id="price-postfix1" onclick="myFunction(this)" name="price-postfix" type="radio" value="$option1"/>Option1<br>
<input id="price-postfix2" onclick="myFunction(this)" name="price-postfix" type="radio" value="$option2"/>Option1<br>
<input id="price-postfix3" onclick="myFunction(this)" name="price-postfix" type="radio" value="$option3"/>Option1<br>

function myFunction(obj){
    document.getElementById('price-postfix').value = obj.value;
}
```